# vertx application not running

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

i am learning Java vertx and have issue with deploy my vertical app plus try it with hibernate

on main class i have try this
`*
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Stage.SessionFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName(args))
  .unwrap(Stage.SessionFactory.class);
3. Project repository
BookingRepository projectRepository = new BookingRepositoryImp(emf);

// 4. Project service
BookingService projectService = new BookingServiceImp(projectRepository);
BookingHandler bookingHandler = new BookingHandler(projectService);

5. WebVerticle
BookingRouter verticle = new BookingRouter(bookingHandler);
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
vertx.deployVerticle(verticle, options)
  .onFailure(err -> err.printStackTrace())
 .onSuccess(res -> {
   System.out.println(res);
   System.out.println("Application is up and running");
  });
}

public static String persistenceUnitName(String[] args) {
return args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "postgresql-example";
}
 }
```

`*`

on vertx mainVerticle i try this
`public void start(Promise<Void> promise) { Stage.SessionFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgresql-example") .unwrap(Stage.SessionFactory.class); // 3. Project repository BookingRepository projectRepository = new BookingRepositoryImp(emf);`

```
// 4. Project service
BookingService projectService = new BookingServiceImp(projectRepository);
BookingHandler bookingHandler = new BookingHandler(projectService);

// 5. WebVerticle
BookingRouter bookingRouter = new BookingRouter(bookingHandler,vertx);

final Router router = Router.router(vertx);
bookingRouter.setRouter(router);

buildHttpServer(vertx, promise, router);
}
```

`* private void buildHttpServer(Vertx vertx, Promise<Void> promise, Router router) {` 
 `vertx.createHttpServer() .requestHandler(router) .listen(8888, http -> { if (http.succeeded()) { promise.complete(); LOGGER.info("running on port : "+8888); } else { promise.fail(http.cause()); LOGGER.info(http.cause()); } }); }`

`public static String persistenceUnitName(String[] args) { return args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "postgresql-example"; }`

on first main i only get result once after that the vertx show it is finish

on second on it isn't run at all and got this
`Jul 09, 2023 6:51:50 PM org.hibernate.reactive.pool.impl.DefaultSqlClientPoolConfiguration poolOptions INFO: HR000025: Connection pool size: 10 Jul 09, 2023 6:51:51 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 2355 ms, time limit is 2000 ms Jul 09, 2023 6:51:52 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 3355 ms, time limit is 2000 ms`

for more info this is repo of app https://github.com/abdullahalmasri/vertx.4.4.0_hibernate.git

Comment: The formatting makes it difficult to follow what you are asking but you are doing a blocking operation on the event loop but not sure what - probably the hibernate initailization. Need to debug more where it is coming from. Do you have to use hibernate though - vertx's own mysql/psql clients are/should be preferred?

Comment: yes,that right there are many blocking thread happen to my code,and yes it seems the initialization is wrong, i am learning vert.x since 2 days, and i have seen many project built using hibernate, so i was trying build my own project , i have detect that my problem happen when it try to read the schema, i have seen in this blog https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/ solution for my issue but still unable to know where i should do the executeBlocking topic : 1.2.4, and thank you for response,

Comment: You should start your learning from here so that you don't learn bad habits  - https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

Comment: i help devs learn and build vertx applications  - if you need 1 on 1 sessions you can reach out via https://consulting.aawadia.dev/

Comment: There is a how-to for Vert.x with Hibernate Reactive on vertx.io: https://how-to.vertx.io/hibernate-reactive-howto/

Comment: @OliverMarienfeld i will check this one right now